# How to toggle display of filesystems in "Places" menu?

Tags: nautilus, menu, gnome-panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selective mounted volumes for the GNOME Desktop and Nautilus Sidebar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2280/selective-mounted-volumes-for-the-gnome-desktop-and-nautilus-sidebar)

Under Places menu in gnome-panel and in the side-pane of Nautilus browser a list of all filesystem on my HD is shown. Is it possible to choose which one should be shown and keep the rest hidden?

Comment: yeap, looks like that

Answer (score 1):

You need program called **Storage device Manager**. This problem has been also solved in this [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=855523&highlight=hide+drives) (look at the last post).

regards

Comment: The post you linked to has no mention of "Storage Manager".

Comment: Actually last post says it... you have to install Storage device manager from ubuntu software center.. good luck xD