# How do I remove partitions in the 'Places' section of the Gnome file dialog?

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selective mounted volumes for the GNOME Desktop and Nautilus Sidebar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2280/selective-mounted-volumes-for-the-gnome-desktop-and-nautilus-sidebar)

In the Gnome file dialog under 'Places' I can add and edit bookmarks to directories. That list however not only contains my bookmarks, but also a list of all partitions on the system that Gnome seems to gather automatically. I can't edit that list as the right-click-menu items for that are grayed out.

How can I get rid of those automatically generated entries and limit it to just my bookmarks?

Comment: yes, the solution is in the post fluteflute linked to above

Comment: I thought this seemed familiar.