# How do I hide CIFS volumes in the Places menu?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, menu

I originally started an Ubuntu forums post about this but I never received any responses.  Anyways, I've got my Documents, Music, Pictures, and Videos folders pointing to Samba shares on my server via CIFS volumes mounted in my fstab file. The problem is I end up with duplicate entries in the Places menu.

I can remove the bookmarks for those folders but then the menu looks ugly as the mounted volumes are still displayed and I can't find a way change their icons in the menu.  I've circled the offending menu entries in the screenshot.  How can I hide them?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have updated my answer and it's working.Check it...

Comment: You might find the answers to [Selective mounted volumes for the GNOME Desktop and Nautilus Sidebar](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2280/selective-mounted-volumes-for-the-gnome-desktop-and-nautilus-sidebar) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@[fluteflute](https://askubuntu.com/users/866/fluteflute):  The answer in the question you linked helped guide me to a workable solution.  What I ended up doing was changing the mount points from my `/home` folder to the `/mnt` folder in the `/etc/fstab` file and then replacing the folders in my home directory with symbolic links to the mounted locations.

`ln -s /mnt/documents/ /home/ramon/Documents`

It's all good now!  My Documents, Video, Music, and Pictures folders no longer have duplicate entries in the places menu and are still mapped to the remote file system on my server.  Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 4):

- You can hide the volumes in Places Menu.Type the following in terminal to create a new file **hide-partitions.rules** under **/etc/udev/rules.d**

  `sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/hide-partitions.rules`
- Now copy/paste the following to **hide-partitions.rules**

  > ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="hide_partition_end"
  >   SUBSYSTEM!="block", GOTO="hide_partition_end"
  >   KERNEL=="loop*|ram*", GOTO="hide_partition_end"
  >   KERNEL=="sda5", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
  >   LABEL="hide_partition_end"
- Save the file and close it.
- Now we are going to hide the partition **sda6**(Stuffs) from Places Menu.
  [image]
- Edit the fstab file

  `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`
- Put a # in front of the line

  `UUID=B630D52430D4EC7D /media/sda6  ntfs-3g  defaults,locale=en_IN  0  0`
- So it becomes

  `#UUID=B630D52430D4EC7D /media/sda6  ntfs-3g   defaults,locale=en_IN  0  0`
- Save the file.
- Reboot the sytem.
- Now the volume Stuffs will be removed from the Places Menu.
  [image]

Comment: Well, they are all currently mounted to their respective folders in my /home directory as opposed to /media.  You gave me an idea though.  Maybe I can mount them in /mnt in fstab and then --bind them to the home folders via a startup script.

Comment: Is sda5 in the line KERNEL=="sda5", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1" supposed to be sda6 (in your example anyways)?  Also, what can I "man" to learn the syntax for this file?  I have multiple partitions to try this on.  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to hide **sda6** then change the line to the following 
`KERNEL=="sda6", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"` suppose if you want to hide another partition say **sda7** just add one more line 
`KERNEL=="sda7", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"`

Comment: Well, I finally got a chance to try this today.  It's a great answer but it doesn't work for CIFS mounts.  The entries in my fstab file look like this:

"//<ip_address>/documents /home/ramon/Documents smbfs iocharset=utf8,credentials=/home/ramon/.smbcredentials,gid=1000 0 0"

There is no device name to add to the .rules file.  Thanks for the answer anyways.