# Remove unwanted Mount option from Places Menu

Tags: mount, places, share, unmount

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hide CIFS volumes in the Places menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16904/how-do-i-hide-cifs-volumes-in-the-places-menu)

On Ubuntu 10.10, 
I added a CIFS network share into `/etc/fstab` using `/media/pub` as my mount point. 
The share becomes visible on the Desktop and under Places (drive icon), which is what I want. But the problem is, Ubuntu 10.10 (unlike 10.04) creates another entry under Places with same name "pub", except this appears to be a mount shortcut rather than another link to the share. When I move my mouse over it says "Mount pub" and if I click on it, it will mount the share and again each time (if already mounted) - it does not display contents of share. In either case, an error pops up soon after "Unable to mount pub - Timeout waiting for mount to appear".

The share itself is accessible, but I can't unmount via GUI, system reports its mounted multiple times and I have to unmount via terminal `sudo umount -a`.
As I'm mounting the share at boot time, I don't need this manual option under Places. Is there an easy way to stop Ubuntu from listing it under Places?

I have tried making the mount point under `/mnt`, this fixes the problem, except creates another as it removes the drive icon from Desktop and Places. I could create a bookmark, but just wondered if there's an easy fix to this unwanted entry under Places.

Thanks

Comment: I came across this post before I posted my question. Don't believe the situation is the same. The two duplicate icons under my Places menu, behave very differently to each other.

Answer (score 0):

you must have using wrong mount command to auto mount the partition. I was facing the similar issue and resolved by using a small utility called : "Storage Device manager".
You can install it from "Ubuntu Software Center". Remove any mount option you have added in the /etc/fstab and use that utility to auto-mount the partitions.

This will Definitely resolve your problem...

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. In the meantime have solved this for the moment, by adding the mount point under /mnt instead. It does not have the annoying mount icon in Places menu. I have created a bookmark and a shortcut on Desktop for access to the share.