# Can/should I unmount DELLUTILITY?

Tags: mount, filesystem

I'm using a Dell with Windows and I am also using Ubuntu as a 2nd OS by wubi. When I boot into ubuntu I have two Hard drive icons one labeled DELLUTILITY and the other labled as recovery on my desktop.  These really annoy me.  I can unmount them but I'm worried that this will cuase a problem to my computer or even mess up windows when I boot into it.

What can I do or should I do?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [How do I hide CIFS volumes in the Places menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16904/how-do-i-hide-cifs-volumes-in-the-places-menu) and [Selective mounted volumes for the GNOME Desktop and Nautilus Sidebar](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2280/selective-mounted-volumes-for-the-gnome-desktop-and-nautilus-sidebar)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to unmount the DELLUTILITY partition at anytime. Mamually, enter the command:

```
sudo umount <mount point>
```

If you want to avoid having the partition always mounting, first get the actual partition name that contains the Dell Utility. To do this, enter the command:

```
mount
```

and see which one it is, for example, `/dev/sda1` or a long series of digits.

as root (sudo), edit the file `/etc/fstab` and remove (or comment out) the line that mounts that partition.

This will disablemounting this partition in the future, but will not prevent you from manually mounting it manually.